# How to get the count of records from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like below

```
Table 1 : 

Id  User_id  rating1  rating2 rating3 

1     4       4         3      5 
2     4       5         2      2
3     1       5         5      5
4     4       1         2      3 


Table 2 : 

Id  User  rating1   rating2  rating3 comment 
1    1      5          2          1   okay
2    4      2          4          4   good
```

I want to get the count of user_id who having rating1 value between  1 , 2 ,  3, 4, 5 and who having rating2 value between  1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5 and who having rating3 value between  1 , 2 , 3, 4, 5

I am trying the following way ,

```
select count(Table1.User_id) 
from Table1
join Table2
  on Table1.User_id = Table2.User 
where Table1.rating1  = ( 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5)  
  and Table2.rating1 = ( 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 )
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What means *But its not working* ? Any error message or an unexpected result?

Comment: unexpected result like No Records found

Comment: Try to use `in (1,2,3,4,5)` istead of ` = ( 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5) `

Comment: But it returns the over all count . i want count of users who's  having the  of rating1  = 1  like all 5

Comment: Then use `where rating1 = 1`

Comment: What is your expected output and why? Would be nice if you include a bigger example data so we can understand what user count and which one dont.

Comment: But it returns the rating1 is 1 . i want count of rating1 = 2  and count of rating1 = 3  and  count of rating1 = 4  and count of rating1 =5  in a single query

Comment: Your tables doesnt have `building_id` OR `rate_memory`  field.

Comment: sorry my query is select count(table1.User_id) 
from table1 
join table2
  on table1.User_id = table2.user 
where table1.rating1 = ( 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5)  
  and rable2.rating1 = ( 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 )

Comment: Is OK, just edit your question. Still waiting for your desire output. For example user 4 has `table1.rating1`  only `{1,5,4}`  and `table2.rating1` `{2}` that count?

Comment: In your question you mention table2.rating2 and rating3 ... but you query show table2.rating. and you dont have rating. and you dont use rating3

Comment: yes . My expected Result is like below , 

count(user_id) with rating1 as 1  = 2 ,  count(user_id) with rating1 as 2  = 1 ,  count(user_id) with rating1 as 3  = 0 , count(user_id) with rating1 as 4  =  1  ,  count(user_id) with rating1 as 5  = 4 ,

Comment: You have to explain that logic. Because `rating1 = 1` appear only on `Table1.rating1` for `id = 4` but you say count should be 2 ? and for 5 you say `count= 4` but only 3 rows has `rating1 = 5`.

Comment: Actually it was an example result

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment, your query is very far from your desire result.

You need to pivot your table to be a single column

```
SELECT rating, count(*)
FROM (
      SELECT `User_id` , `rating1` as rating FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `User_id` , `rating2` as rating FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `User_id` , `rating3` as rating FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `User`    , `rating1` as rating FROM Table2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `User`    , `rating2` as rating FROM Table2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `User`    , `rating3` as rating FROM Table2
   ) as combine
GROUP BY rating
ORDER BY rating
```

Comment: thanks for you answer but it display the overall count only

Comment: Ok, let me check again.

Answer (score 0):

Use IN (1,2,3,4,5) Insted of = (1,2,3,4,5)

It will give error of multiple oprands since equal can be use when it comes to compare one on one value.

```
SELECT t1.user_id,t2.user,count(*) as Count_Rate
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE rating1 IN ('1','2','3','4','5')) as t1
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE rating1 IN ('1','2','3','4','5')) as t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user
GROUP by user_id
```

Or You can try this also by adding,

```
(SELECT *,count(rating1='1') AS rate1 FROM table1 WHERE rating1 IN ('1','2','3','4','5')) as t1
```